# Iterate through an array of arbitrary dimension

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, algorithm

Using c#, how to iterate through an multidimensional array of *unknown* dimensions?

For example consider setting each element of the array to a specified value, all entries of the array needs to be iterated. The method should handle all the following cases and fill all entries with the value 4, regardless of the dimension of the array passed.

```
ClearArray(new int[3], 4);
ClearArray(new int[3,3], 4);
ClearArray(new int[3, 3, 3, 3], 4);
```

The methods signature obviously looks something like

```
static void ClearArray(Array a, int val) { ... }
```

I know how to iterate through *one* dimension:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.GetLength(dimension); i++) 
{
    ...
}
```

**Note**: This question is not about 2D arrays, 3D arrays, nor 4D arrays. It should handle whatever dimension the `Rank` property on the `Array` object says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fastest solution is Buffer.BlockCopy:

```
static void ClearArray(Array array, int val)
{
  var helper = Enumerable.Repeat(val, Math.Min(array.Length, 1024)).ToArray();
  var itemSize = 4;


  Buffer.BlockCopy(helper, 0, array, 0, helper.Length * itemSize);
  for (var len = helper.Length; len < array.Length; len *= 2)
  {
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, array, len * itemSize, Math.Min(len, array.Length - len) * itemSize);
  }
}

static int Count(Array array, Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
  var helper = new int[Math.Min(array.Length, 4096)];
  var itemSize = 4;

  var count = 0;
  for (var offset = 0; offset < array.Length; offset += helper.Length)
  {
    var len = Math.Min(helper.Length, array.Length - offset);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, offset * itemSize, helper, 0, len * itemSize);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
      if (predicate(helper[i]))
        count++;
  } 
  return count;
}
```

Statistic:

```
time: 00:00:00.0449501, method: Buffer.BlockCopy
time: 00:00:01.4371424, method: Lexicographical order
time: 00:00:01.3588629, method: Recursed
time: 00:00:06.2005057, method: Cartesian product with index array reusing
time: 00:00:08.2433531, method: Cartesian product w/o index array reusing
```

Statistic (Count function):

```
time: 00:00:00.0812866, method: Buffer.BlockCopy
time: 00:00:02.7617093, method: Lexicographical order
```

Code:

```
  Array array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), new[] { 100, 200, 400 }, new[] { -10, -20, 167 });
  foreach (var info in new [] 
    { 
      new {Name = "Buffer.BlockCopy", Method = (Action<Array, int>)ClearArray_BufferCopy},
      new {Name = "Lexicographical order", Method = (Action<Array, int>)ClearArray_LexicographicalOrder}, 
      new {Name = "Recursed", Method = (Action<Array, int>)ClearArray_Recursed}, 
      new {Name = "Cartesian product with index array reusing", Method = (Action<Array, int>)ClearArray_Cartesian_ReuseArray}, 
      new {Name = "Cartesian product w/o index array reusing", Method = (Action<Array, int>)ClearArray_Cartesian}, 
    }
   )
  {
    var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();
    var count = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      info.Method(array, i);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("time: {0}, method: {1}", TimeSpan.FromTicks(stopwatch.Elapsed.Ticks / count), info.Name);
  }
```

Comment: +1 for speedy solution and even a cmoparision! Only works for filling an array though, not iterating through it. For example count the number of non-zero entries or such won't fit in this picture.

Comment: @vidstige Count method with Buffer.BlockCopy is fastest any way (see example above). Eric don't like multi-dim array and so they worked in .net slowly :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [Lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order):
Index is sequence of "digits". On each iteration last "digit" incremented while it in bounds, then next "digit" incremented,  etc

```
Func<Array, int[]> firstIndex = 
  array => Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank)
         .Select(_i => array.GetLowerBound(_i))
         .ToArray();

Func<Array, int[], int[]> nextIndex = (array, index) => 
  {
    for (int i = index.Length-1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
       index[i]++;
       if (index[i] <= array.GetUpperBound(i))
         return index;
       index[i] = array.GetLowerBound(i);
    }
    return null;
  };

for (var index = firstIndex(array); index != null; index = nextIndex(array, index))
{
   var v = array.GetValue(index);
   ...
   array.SetValue(newValue, index);
}
```

Comment: clever! But how to iterate through the lexicographical order? If I start at [0,0,...,0] whats the next indices? And how do I know when all indices are iterated?

Comment: thanks! Works like a charm. Some quirk in there makes it skip the last index in each dimension.

Answer (score 6):

You can build a solution out of a bunch of parts. The sketch of the solution is: make a bunch of sequences from zero to length-1, one sequence for each dimension of the array. Then take the Cartesian product of those sequences. That gives you a sequence of indexes.

Let's start with the product:

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences) 
{ 
  IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> emptyProduct = 
    new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() }; 
  return sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) => 
      from accseq in accumulator 
      from item in sequence 
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item})); 
}
```

I discuss how this code works here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx

We need a sequence of sequences. What sequences?

```
var sequences = from dimension in Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank)
        select Enumerable.Range(array.GetLowerBound(dimension), array.GetLength(dimension));
```

So we have sequences as, say:

```
{
   { 0, 1, 2 },
   { 0, 1, 2, 3 }
}
```

Now compute the product:

```
var product = sequences.CartesianProduct();
```

So the product is

```
{
   { 0, 0 },
   { 0, 1 },
   { 0, 2 },
   { 0, 3 },
   { 1, 0 },
   { 1, 1 },
   { 1, 2 },
   { 1, 3 },
   { 2, 0 },
   { 2, 1 },
   { 2, 2 },
   { 2, 3 }
}
```

And now you can say

```
foreach(IEnumerable<int> indices in product)
    array.SetValue(value, indices.ToArray());
```

Does that all make sense?

Comment: yes, it does makes a lot of sense! Very pedagogically and clearly written. Thank you.

Comment: @EricLippert `select Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetUpperBound(dimension));` should be `select Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(dimension));` I believe.  Consider the case of a single dimensional array of size 1.  UpperBound will be 0, range will return 0 values, when it should return 1.  Range takes a count, not a value to go to.

Comment: @DarkGray Well, if you have a lot of dimensions and/or large lengths it's a slow operation.  There's no real way around that...

Comment: @Servy in this solution big count of memory allocation. index array allocated on each iteraion.

Comment: @Servy: You are correct. Serves me right for not testing the code.

Comment: @DarkGray: I agree with you. However, look at the bigger picture. The original poster is *filling in an array of unknown dimension dynamically by calling a helper method*. That is already *far* slower than filling in an array of single dimension. If this code is so performance sensitive that every nanosecond counts, then the game is already lost; you shouldn't be doing this sort of thing in the first place if you have really tight performance requirements. Moreover: is this *the slowest thing in the program*? If not then *there is a bigger problem somewhere else to fix first.*

Comment: @DarkGray: Moreover, you seem to think that the array *allocation* is the slow bit here. Allocating an array takes on the order of nanoseconds, and filling it in takes not much longer. The actual performance cost here is more likely to be the *collection pressure* of making all those arrays. If either is a problem then it is easy enough to write your own implementation of ToArray that takes the array to fill in **if profiling measurements indicate that the array allocation is in fact the most expensive cost in the program.**

Comment: @EricLippert Allocation is fast, but array copy and gc is not. Also in each yield method (Concat, Select, etc) helper object allocated.

Comment: @EricLippert Performance overhead for pretty and small code in range 10-30% is normal. Performance overhead in 20000% is terrific (~3000% for index checking and ~500% for functional paradigm). See measusing below

Answer (score 4):

A simple 2-step solution, no optimization attempted:

```
    public static void ClearArray(Array a, int val)
    {
        int[] indices = new int[a.Rank];
        ClearArray(a, 0, indices, val);
    }

    private static void ClearArray(Array a, int r, int[] indices, int v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.GetLength(r); i++)
        {
            indices[r] = i;

            if (r + 1 < a.Rank)
                ClearArray(a, r + 1, indices, v);
            else
                a.SetValue(v, indices);
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice! Short and clean. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Rank to determine the number of dimensions, then Array.GetLowerBound(int dimension) and Array.GetUpperBound(int dimension) to understand the range for each given rank.

It's not specified how your iterator should work (e.g. are there any semantic to the order of iteration).  However, to implement ClearArray() the order of iteration should not matter.

Use a.SetValue(object value, params int[] indices) to set the value specified for your ClearArray method.

Comment: yeah. I figured that too. We can even use 0-Array.GetLength, right? But how to sew all this togeher? Recursive? Can see it.

Comment: The order of iteration does not matter, any order will work. But each element has to be accessed only once. And the magic indices[] argument passed to SetValue? How do we compute it? Here lies the actual iteration of the array.