# How can I efficiently assign a common initial value to a large array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization

How can I efficiently assign a common initial value to a large array?
For instance if I have a 100 by 100 by 100 integer array where all initial values should be zero.

In matlab I would simply write:

```
array = zeros(100,100,100);
```

How can I do this without a loop in C#?

Comment: In C# all integers are by default initialized to 0.

Comment: Curious: Yes, in the example he gave - but that is not an answer to the question. The question is "`How can I efficiently assign a common initial value to a large array?`"

Comment: @user1323995 please clarify: are you asking about how to make your code as short as possible or as fast as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for the sake of argument (I do not personally think it would be a good programming style) but it can be done in C# in one line and technically without a loop but with LINQ

```
int[,,] cube = new int[A, B, C];
Enumerable.Range(0, A*B*C).Select(i => cube[i/(B*C), i%(B*C)/C, i%C] = 1).Count();
```

Count() here is only necessary to make the sequence to be enumerated, its result is ignored.
This is to implement MATLAB's ones() function. 
To implement zeros() the following can be used:

```
Array.Clear(cube, 0, A*B*C);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void SetAllValues(int[,,] data, int value) {
    for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++) {
            for (int z = 0; z < data.GetLength(2); z++) {
                data[x, y, z] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They specifically said "How can I do this without a loop in C#?"

Comment: It sounds like looping is the proper way to do this to me.  That's like somebody asking how can I do this without using variables. Instead of trying to figure that out, I'd rather convince them that they should be using variables.

Comment: Then I think you should have specified why you recommend a loop in the answer, instead of just throwing code out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.Repeat` for that purpose like so:

```
int[] zeros1Dim = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 100).ToArray();
int[][] zeros2Dim = Enumerable.Repeat(zeros1Dim, 100).ToArray();
int[][][] array = Enumerable.Repeat(zeros2Dim, 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: Probably not the most efficient since the array will be larger than necessary. `Enumerable.Repeat.ToArray` does not know how large the sequnce is, hence it needs to double the size of the array consecutively. Here's a related question to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519275/high-memory-consumption-with-enumerable-range

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an idiomatic, non-loop way of initializing arrays in C#, and based on the answers here, it seems like neither do others. Unsafe memory copying could require fewer lines of code, though it really muddies the meaning of what you're doing: it emphasizes the mechanism (move this value to this memory address) over the semantics (make this entire multi-dimensional array equal to the same value.)

Given that, my suggestion would be to bite the bullet, use a loop, but then *abstract it away in a pleasantly named method*:

```
public static T[,,] FillArrayWithValue<T>(this T[,,] array, T value)
{
    // Loops go here
}
```

Stick that in a static utility class somewhere, and then your callsite becomes:

```
int[,,] myArray = new int[4, 5, 6];
myArray.FillArrayWithValue(value);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the C programming land it is common to use OS functions like [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) or [CopyMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to efficiently move memory from one place to another. That is far better than using loops because the operating system will use dedicated hardware ([DMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access)) to perform the operation.

I'm not sure if this is useful for your simple case, but it is possible to import these functions from certain DLLs if you want.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr destination, IntPtr source, uint length);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] a = new byte[10]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    byte[] b = new byte[10];

    IntPtr pa = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(a, 0);
    IntPtr pb = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(b, 0);

    CopyMemory(pb, pa, 10);
}
```

The [CopyMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function will only work for contiguous memory blocks, so be aware on how you call it.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

If you look the commentaries below you will notice that the piece of code showed above is far from being "usable" because it can corrupt you application memory without you ever knowing about it. A better approach is to use the [Buffer.BlockCopy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx), as suggested by codesparkle, which probably does same thing internally but in a safe manner:

```
byte[] a = new byte[10]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
byte[] b = new byte[10];
Buffer.BlockCopy(a, 0, b, 0, 10);
```

Comment: But this is unsafe and requires an extra array. You would only use unsafe when performance is very very important and then use FillMemory().

Comment: The main purpose of my answer was to show that it is possible to copy memory from one array to another without using conventional loops. What is interesting is that I was able to run the code posted above without marking **allow unsafe code** in my application. I guess that native win32 functions are assumed to be *memory leak safe*!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure: does this really copy b to a or do you have to UnMarshal to get the results back?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint after the **CopyMemory** call you can see that the values were successfully copied. But thinking again I believe this  has only happened because the array object values were stored in a contiguous block of memory that happend to start at the address returned by **UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement**

Comment: The contiguous is OK but I'm surprised it works without actually pinning the arrays and the really scary part is that you can call `CopyMemory(pb, pa, 20);` and corrupt the heap...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just tried calling **CopyMemory(pb, pa, 10000)** and it executed silently. Not a single exception was thrown, and I was running my app with **allow usafe code** disabled.

Comment: Instead of DLL-importing, I would *strongly* recommend using [Buffer.BlockCopy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916444/1106367)

Comment: The reason this "works" is that you got lucky and the array wasn't moved before calling `CopyMemory()`. You're completely ignoring the **OfPinnedArray** portion of the call: your array is **not** pinned, so at that point you're just gambling that the GC doesn't run and invalidate your "address". Beyond that, you don't need unsafe turned on to p/invoke; what a function in a DLL does is (usually) not the concern of the C# compiler.